# Imprimir valores en una matriz NXN

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código que me imprime un valor de forma horizontal y quiero que se imprima como una matriz **nxn** , aquí mi código:

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');

        $sq2 = "SELECT * FROM acarga WHERE bl3 = '1' ";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($connex, $sq2);

                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))

     $test = $row2['bl3'];

    echo $test ;

    }
?>
```

[image: Que se imrpima de esta forma]

Comment: Falta una apertura de llave "{"

Comment: pon el ejemplo de como se está imprimiendo y como quieres que se imprima

Comment: @Sr1871 se imprime horizontal, quiero que se imprima dentreo de 3 columnas con la cantidad de filas segun el resultado

Comment: Muestra como se imprime..

Comment: pon in ejemplo gráfico para que sea más fácil

Comment: Añadí una imagen, disculpen la demora